# How to Expand specific kendo UI treeList node after tree data gets loaded?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

> I have used transport funtion to read the data for tree list :

```
 var drillDownDataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
```

> I want to expand first two parent items in tree list after data gets
>   loaded and fire ajax call to get data on child items.
>   
>   Expand function is there but it do not give call to server side method.

Comment: You need to provide some code. What you have posted here is not enough.

Comment: By the way, if this question is a Kendo asp.net MVC question, how come your code is not razor?

Answer (score 0):

Just tell the [TreeList .expand()](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treelist#methods-expand) function what you want to expand.

```
$('#treeList').data('kendoTreeList').expand('.k-first, .k-first + .k-item');
```